# E-mail dialog box is not open in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, addressbook

In my app, I am fetching the e-mail id from address box using PersonPicker view.

When i select any e-mail id, i try to open the e-mail dialog. But it will just open & close immediatly.

I can't able to solve this issue.

I got code from [Here](http://gabriel-tips.blogspot.in/2012/02/how-to-import-contacts-from-address.html)

My code is as follow:

```
-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier{

    // Get the first and the last name. Actually, copy their values using the person object and the appropriate
    // properties into two string variables equivalently.
    // Watch out the ABRecordCopyValue method below. Also, notice that we cast to NSString *.
    NSString *firstName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    NSString *lastName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

    // Compose the full name.
    NSString *fullName = @"";
    // Before adding the first and the last name in the fullName string make sure that these values are filled in.
    if (firstName != nil) {
        fullName = [fullName stringByAppendingString:firstName];
    }
    if (lastName != nil) {
        fullName = [fullName stringByAppendingString:@" "];
        fullName = [fullName stringByAppendingString:lastName];
    }


    // Get the multivalue e-mail property.
    CFTypeRef multivalue = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);

    // Get the index of the selected e-mail. Remember that the e-mail multi-value property is being returned as an array.
    CFIndex index = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(multivalue, identifier);

    // Copy the e-mail value into a string.
    email = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multivalue, index);
    NSLog(@"%@",email);
    // Create a temp array in which we'll add all the desired values.
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tempArray addObject:fullName];

    // Save the email into the tempArray array.
    [tempArray addObject:email];


    // Now add the tempArray into the contactsArray.
    [contactsArray addObject:tempArray];
    NSLog(@"%@",contactsArray);
    // Release the tempArray.
    [tempArray release];

    // Reload the table to display the new data.
    [table reloadData];

    // Dismiss the contacts view controller.
    [contacts dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [contacts release];


    MFMailComposeViewController* Apicker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if (Apicker != nil)
    {

        [Apicker setSubject:@""];
        NSString * someString = nil;
        someString=@"<a href=\"https://www.google.com\">Google</a>";
        [Apicker setMessageBody:someString isHTML:YES];

        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:email, nil];
        [Apicker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

        Apicker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:Apicker animated:YES];
        [Apicker release];

    }



    return NO;
}
```

**I think it may be the issue of dismiss & present the modal view.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem with dismiss and present is that the two overlap. -- dismiss it and THEN show it kinda like you did BUT you run into a problem because the stuff is animated. dont animate there or delay the presetting till after the dismissal

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I did exactly same as you but i want to show mail dialog when the user choose any e-mail id. How can i do this?

Comment: Great coding...!! Wow, i can't believe that just like silly mistake, it make like this. Thanks a lot again!!